# What is the difference between “anybody”, “nobody”, “everyone”, and “everybody”? How are they used?

Tags: usage

How are these pronouns placed and used in AmE?

Answer (score 2):

Anybody - Means **any one** from (say) a Group.
Nobody  -  Means **none** from a Group.
These two were pretty obvious, Yes.

Now, **everyone** and **everybody** actually means the same. It means **Every Person**.

However, the difference comes in usage. *Everyone* is considered a bit formal while *Everybody* is more casual.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Note all three have "one" and "body" versions: "anyone", "anybody", "everyone", "everybody", "no one", "nobody". ("no one" is written as two words because otherwise the two "o"s in row would confuse the pronunciation.) Both versions of each mean the same thing.